# how to use location.href from the ts file instead of router.navigate in Angular 8 and what to import?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

on success i need to route to a different home page...  how to use window.location.href? where to import window from?

```
@Input() redirectTo: string = "/home";

 switch (data.authenticationStatus.value) {
  case "SUCCESS":
    this.storageSvc.saveTokens(data.tokens);
    window.location.href([this.redirectTo]);
    break;
```

Comment: The above doesnt work ... please help

Comment: ok this code is in an angular library and home page is with in another application where the library is used. So do u think router will still work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Routing externally**

Good old fashioned javascript will work if you want to navigate outside of your app:

```
window.location.href = externalUrl;
```

**Routing internally**

You use the Angular router to navigate to a new route. The router is imported from `@angular/router`, and you inject it via the component's constructor.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class MyComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  @Input() redirectTo: string = "/home"

  navigate() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(this.redirectTo);
  }
}
```

If you have a fully formed relative url, as it appears you do, then you can call `router.navigateByUrl(url)`. There are more complicated ways of building navigation instructions, but I want to focus on the basics here to introduce you to routing.

Comment: ok this code is in angular library and home page is with in another application where the library is used. So do u think router will still work?

Comment: No, just use window.location.href = url. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use this? Angular is a single Page Application framework, so normally you don't go to another html-page or something inside your project - as it's just one big single webpage.
By using the router, you can get something like multiple pages, but be aware that in the background it always falls back to your index.html...

Comment: ok this code is in angular library and home page is with in another application where the library is used. So do u think router will still work?